# How can I find the Word List or dictionary with Polarity Score of TextBlob?

Tags: python, textblob, word-list

I need the total list or dictionary with Polarity Score of TextBlob. I search many online sites but can not find the list. I know the way to get polarity of a sentence or word. How can I find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,  [In thisLink](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/eb08c120d364e908646731d60b4e4c6c1712ff63/textblob/en/en-sentiment.xml#L2931), you can find around 2900+ words with polarity, subjectivity, intensity, and meaning(sense) of TextBlob.

Answer (score 2):

As we did not see a direct api function, may be you can try this.
You said you know the way to get polarity of a word.

Get the complete word list from `TextBlob`.

Copied from API

```
from textblob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.")
b.words
```

Now iterate each word, get polarity of each word and prepare your own list.

Comment: Thank You. But I need the complete list for aspect-based sentiment analysis to compare.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I will check

Comment: Did you refer this article : https://towardsdatascience.com/aspect-based-sentiment-analysis-using-spacy-textblob-4c8de3e0d2b9

Comment: You may need spacy library along with TextBlob

Comment: I already did aspect-based sentiment analysis using spacy.  I need to build a dictionary with polarity scores that are not in the Textblob Dictionary. That's why I need the list of textblob dictionary